# permission to access another frame

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

if i delete one of the permission, the GUI will show, but if I added both of them, the GUI won't show and this error came :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError: The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects.

I have a jframe called FMenuMasterAgama to open FCariMasterAgama and FCariMasterAgama want to access table on FMenuMasterAgama
here is my code on FMenuMasterAgama :

```
public class FMenuMasterAgama extends javax.swing.JFrame {
koneksi konek;
Connection conn=null;
Statement stmt= null;
ResultSet rs = null;
FUbahMasterAgama ubahmasteragama;
FMasterAgama tambahagama;
FCariMasterAgama carimaster;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
/**
 * Creates new form FMenuMasterNegara
 */
public FMenuMasterAgama() {
    initComponents();
    konek = new koneksi();
    ubahmasteragama = new FUbahMasterAgama();
    tambahagama = new FMasterAgama();
    carimaster = new FCariMasterAgama();
    loadtable();

}
```

here is my code from FCariMasterAgama :

```
public class FCariMasterAgama extends javax.swing.JFrame {
koneksi konek;
FMenuMasterAgama menu;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
/**
 * Creates new form FCariMasterAgama
 */
public FCariMasterAgama() {
    initComponents();
    konek = new koneksi();
    menu =  new FMenuMasterAgama();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(FCariMasterAgama.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```